# What's the difference between ng-model and standard two-way data binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

There are two ways of setting up two-directional data binding in angularjs.

### Two-way data binding

One is by defining two-way data binding in isolate scope:

```
scope: {
     myValue: '='
}
```

Watch changes with `$scope.$watch`, and set changes with `$scope.myValue = newVal`.

### ng-model

The other is by using `ng-model`. Define this in your app with `require: '?ngModel'`. Watch for changes with `$scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel)`, and set changes with `ngModel.$setViewValue`.

Obviously there are differences in method names, etc., between these two, but how are they different in spirit? Where should I use `ng-model`, and where should I use two-way data binding?

Answer (score 0):

With a primitive the directive scope's property gets a copy of the parent scope's value. Changes to one do not affect the other.

With an object, both the parent scope and the directive scope have a reference to the same (one) object. Changes in either affect the same object.

Comment: Wait, can't you use both primitives and objects with both two-way data binding and ng-model?